# Sockets server and client in the same python script

Tags: python, sockets

The below code does not work, when I keep both socket server and client code in the same script file where I run server in the main thread and the client in a separate thread using **start_new_thread**

```
import socket, sys
from thread import *

host = socket.gethostname()
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    s.bind((host, 8888))
except socket.error as msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()
s.listen(10)

def clientthread(conn):
    conn.send('Welcome to the server. Type something and hit enter\n')
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        reply = 'OK...' + data
        if not data:
            break
        conn.sendall(reply)
    conn.close()

while 1:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])
    start_new_thread(clientthread ,(conn,))
s.close()
```

Comment: Is there an error message?... By the way, you cannot connect the same client twice to the same server. This will lead to a socket error.

Comment: AFAIK, this code does what it is asked to: it listens on port 8888, accept incoming connections and launches a new thread to echo data on that connection. What it your problem? Without more details, the question is off topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you `bind()` to your `gethostname()`, you also have to connect to that interface from the client, even if it is on the same computer. `"localhost"` or `"127.0.0.1"` will not work. If you want them to work, either `bind()` to them directly, or bind to everything (`"0.0.0.0"` or just an empty string, `""`).

Low-budget test code:

```
from _thread import *
import socket,time

def client():
    print("Thread starts")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Thread connects")
    sock=socket.create_connection((socket.gethostname(),8888))
    #sock=socket.create_connection(("localhost",8888))
    print("Thread after connect")
    sock.sendall(b"Hello from client")
    sock.close()
    print("Thread ends")

serv=socket.socket()
serv.bind((socket.gethostname(),8888))
#serv.bind(("localhost",8888))
#serv.bind(("0.0.0.0",8888))
#serv.bind(("",8888))
serv.listen(10)
start_new_thread(client,())
print("Before accept")
s,c=serv.accept()
print("After accept "+c[0])
print("Message: "+s.recv(1024).decode("ASCII"))
s.close()
serv.close()
```

Feel free to experiment with testing the various sock+bind combinations.